# What does the symbol "That" mean in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I've seen several examples of code using the symbol "That" with Generics. i.e.

```
def map[B, That](f : (A) => B) : That
```

But, due to the lack of google-ability of that word, I can't find any documentation on what it does or how I use it.

Is it simply a normal type placeholder, or does it do something special?

Comment: it's a placeholder - yes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any identifiers inside `[...]` are treated as type parameters.

So in case of `def map[B, That](f : (A) => B) : That` `That` only means a generic return type. Replace it with `Z` for example: `def map[B, Z](f : (A) => B) : Z` would have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Translating to Java, that would be:

```
public <B, That> That map(f: Function1<A, B>)
```

Or, in other words, `That` is a generic (or, in Scala lingo, a type parameter).

Answer (score 3):

It's a "placeholder" as you call it (that is, a type parameter); the convention in the collections library is to use `That` to represent the type of the collection that will be created.  (Thus, you transform from `this` to `That`.)

Comment: Calling it a "placeholder" is at best misleading. It's a formal type parameter just as "regular" (value) argument names in method definitions are formal parameters. It's the type-level counterpart to an argument to a method.

Comment: @RandallSchulz - Indeed, but that's what the OP called it.  I have modified my answer to say what it is and suggest that "placeholder" is not the technically correct term.